# System alerts / errors in B2B web design - How to design system alerts so that users pay attention to them

Tags: web, alerts, b2b, system

I need some support with one problem 
System messages in B2B web applications, specifically about them being ignored by users.
Can you recommend any references or share your experience in designing them?
System messages - I mean messages related to the operation of the system, namely:

```
information about errors in the database
information about upcoming deadlines
warning about unsaved user actions
information about the timeliness of data and the possibility of their supplementation
```

That is, partly about situations not resulting from the user action but from the system.
The assumption is - message recognition, invasiveness in the scope acceptable by the user, creating the feeling of importance for safety and work in the system (but not to treat these messages as a buzzing disturbing fly)
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: What is your main problem? Users are ignoring your messages? How are these presented?

Comment: Start with the long standing guidelines: https://www.nngroup.com/articles/error-message-guidelines/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought about toast messages in the top right of the page? Something that doesn't necessarily distract the user, but can also catch their eye?

[image: Examples of Toast Messages]
[Source](https://dribbble.com/shots/9837444-Toast-Messages-v2)

Another thought, I don't know how you word your messages, but make sure they are simple to understand what you are trying to tell the user. People tend to care more about the message when they understand it.

Example:

> **"Error: datasql123prmtr"** will definitely get ignored.

> **"Error: The value entered exceeds the parameters of xyz"** will tend to get more interaction.